# how to get nearest point to a point in a point array?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to make shape and polygon editor in wpf but not getting exact point nearest to a point in a points.

Help is needed ! Better if a sample of shape or polygon editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the point in the array `points` that is closest to the point `current`:

```
Point closest = points.OrderBy(
  p => Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p.X - current.X, 2.0) + Math.Pow(p.Y - current.Y, 2.0))
).First();
```

Comment: You don't need that `Sqrt` in there.